# Count List Items shown on screen and not overflow

Tags: jquery, count, visible

How can I count all the list items that are displayed on the screen when overflow is set to hidden?

Using the code below still counts all the items, even the ones that overflow.

```
   var count = $("#myList ul li:visible").length;
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kPAwX/2/

Comment: `:visible` selects the elements that don't have `display:none` property, you should use methods like `offset` or `position` and filter the elements.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var maxh = $("#myList ul").height();
$("#myList ul li").filter(function () {
    return $(this).position().top + $(this).height() < maxh;
});
```

This will select all of the `li`s that are completely visible.  If an `li` is partially cut off, it will be filtered.

If you want even partially visible `li`s to not be filtered, simply remove the addition of the height (or create your own cut off any way you want).

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/z6GXA/