# Count Table Rows Hidden In Overflow with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

I have a bootstrap 3 dashboard where I am hiding the overflow in a particular div. I need to be able to identify the number of table rows hidden in the overflow that are not visible in the div. jQuery method preferred but vanilla JS also fine.

have been trying to sort this out and have not been able to find any ways so far to count the number of rows that are hidden in overflow.

NB: There is no markup difference between the rows that are visible and those that are not visible as CSS is used to hide the excess rows using `overflow: hidden;` on the parent DIV.

Thanks.

Additional #1
Here is the HTML I am working with. The height is set by javscript at runtime.

```html
<div id="jobs-list" class="box-body no-padding job-list" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Account</th>
    <th class="text-center">Due</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 1 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 2 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 3 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 4 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">-- TOMORROW --</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="box-footer text-center">
 152 More Jobs
</div>
```

As you can see in the example above I am using a bootstrap 3 box to contain the data. The height of `.box-body` is set using javascript (which works fine already and is based on the window height). By using the `overflow: hidden;` CSS rule instead of showing scroll bars on `.box-body` the overflow is hidden and not visible. I need to be able to adjust the text in `.box-footer` using javascript to identify the number of rows that are not visible.

Comment: Is there a header? or only body?

Comment: Thanks @Twisty I have added sample HTML to give you an idea of the DOM structure for what I am working with. Unfortunately I don't have any sample javascript on how to count the hidden rows as I haven't even been able to find any pointers in the right direction of where to start.

Comment: Hmm might see is `.is(":visible")` will help.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a mathematical approach to this problem, suppose that all the children have the same height (or width, depends on your aligning) :

```js
console.log($('#main div').length - $('#main').height()/$('#main div').height());
```

```css
#main {
  height:200px; /*Suppose 200px*/
  overflow:hidden;
}
#main div {
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div>
    Hello 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A very good approach however the issue would be with the same row heights as a row can wrap if the job name is longer that normal and I can't truncate the job name as the full name is needed for contextual awareness.

Comment: If the job name is longer, the next row would still be part visible, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers...

I was able to find a way to do this using jQuery and a jQuery extension by Kevin Marx.

Firstly you need to add the jquery.overflowing.js plugin to the page...

```js
/* Overflowing.js
 *
 * A plugin based on Elving Rodriguez's Overflowed
 * http://elvingrodriguez.com/overflowed
 *
 */
(function($){
  $.fn.overflowing = function(options, callback){
    var self = this
    var overflowed = []
    var hasCallback = callback && typeof callback === 'function' ? true : false;
    var status = false
    this.options = options || window

    this.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this)
      elPosition = $this.position()
      elWidth = $this.width()
      elHeight = $this.height()
      var parents = $this.parentsUntil(self.options)
      var $parentsTo = $(self.options)
      parents.push($parentsTo)

      for(var i=0; i<parents.length; i++){
        var parentPosition = $(parents[i]).position()
        var parentWidth = $(parents[i]).width()
        var parentHeight = $(parents[i]).height()
        if ( elPosition.top<0
        || elPosition.left<0
        || elPosition.top>(parentHeight+parentPosition.top)
        || elPosition.left>(parentWidth+parentPosition.left)
        || (elPosition.top + elHeight) > (parentHeight+parentPosition.top)
        || (elPosition.left+elWidth) > (parentWidth+parentPosition.left)){
          status = true
          $(parents[i]).addClass('overflowed')
          overflowed.push(parents[i])
          if (hasCallback) callback(parents[i])
        }
      }

      if($this.parents(self.options).hasClass('overflowed')) $this.addClass('overflowing')
    })

    if (!hasCallback) return overflowed.length > 1 ? overflowed : status
  }

})(jQuery)
```

Then you run...

```
$("tr").overflowing("#jobs-list");
```

Which through the overflowing plugin adds the class `overflowing` to each overflowing row (first selector) within the target parent (second selector).

At this point it is a simple case of using jQuery's `.length` property and a selector to target only the `.overflowing` classes within the target object you are wanting to calculate for, ie...

```
var hiddenRows = $("#jobs-list .overflowing").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure by what you mean by 'hidden by overflow'. Does that mean include stuff that's partially hidden, or things that are fully hidden only? My solution includes partially hidden as 'not hidden'.

Regardless, `offset` is your best solution.

```js
let jobs = $("#jobs-list");

let offset = jobs.offset().top;
let height = jobs.height();

let tr = $("tr", $("#jobs-list")).toArray();

let stopped = 0;

for (let i in tr)
{
  let total_offset = $(tr[i]).offset().top - offset;
  if (total_offset >= height)
  {
    stopped = i;
    break;
  }

}

console.log("hidden:", tr.length - stopped);
```

```css
#jobs-list {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jobs-list" class="box-body no-padding job-list" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Account</th>
    <th class="text-center">Due</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 1 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 2 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 3 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-green">-- TODAY --</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Customer 4 (MCB#123456789)<br />
     <small>Job name</small>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">-- TOMORROW --</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="box-footer text-center">
 152 More Jobs
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this: [Count List Items shown on screen and not overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742674/count-list-items-shown-on-screen-and-not-overflow)

Working jQuery example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jzmqfeyj/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  //Add random count of jobs
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); i++) {
    $("#jobs-list tbody").append($("#jobs-list table tbody tr:last").clone());
  }
  console.log("Created", i, "Jobs");
  console.log("Total", $("#jobs-list table tbody tr:not('.header')").length, "Jobs");
  var mh = $("#jobs-list").height();
  var overflowed = $("#jobs-list table tbody tr:not('.header')").filter(function() {
    return $(this).position().top + $(this).height() > mh;
  });
  console.log("Invisible", overflowed.length, "Jobs");
  $(".job-number").html(overflowed.length);
});
```

Since `:visible` counts only items that are `hidden`, you can't really use it. We can `.filter()` on items that are in our "viewport" or not in overflow. We know the height of each element and the div. Anything greater than the height of the div, we count.